# Upload audio file to server on iOS using PhoneGap

Tags: ios, cordova, audio

I'm trying to record audio, save it and upload the file to server.

I have the code that records and saves the recording to Documents folder.

```
function recordAudio() {
    window.src = "myrecording.wav";
    window.mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);

    mediaRec.stop();
    mediaRec.startRecord();

    var recTime = 0;
    setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
    recTime = recTime + 1;
    setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
    }, 1000);
    }
    function stopRecording() {
    mediaRec.stopRecord();
    mediaRec.play();

}
function onSuccess() {
    console.log("recordAudio():Audio Success");
}
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
    'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
function setAudioPosition(position) {
    document.getElementById('audio_position').innerHTML = position;
}
```

I have 2 questions:

1. How to access the recorded file? Where is it located? I've tried `documents://myrecording.wav`. Is it right?
2. How to upload the file to my server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with [media capture plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media-capture) instead of using media plugin

```
var captureSuccess = function(mediaFiles) {
    var i, path, len;
    for (i = 0, len = mediaFiles.length; i < len; i += 1) {
        path = mediaFiles[i].fullPath;
        uploadAudio(path);     
    }
};


var captureError = function(error) {
    navigator.notification.alert('Error code: ' + error.code, null, 'Capture Error');
};

navigator.device.capture.captureAudio(captureSuccess, captureError, {limit:1});
```

If you want to use media plugin, you have to provide a full file url, not just the name, and then use that url to upload the file using [file transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/)

To use [file transfer plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file-transfer/)

```
function uploadAudio(fileURL) {
    var win = function (r) {
        console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
        console.log("Response = " + r.response);
        console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
    }

    var fail = function (error) {
        alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
        console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
    }

    var options = new FileUploadOptions();
    options.fileKey = "file";//the name of the file you expect on the server
    options.fileName = fileURL.substr(fileURL.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

    var ft = new FileTransfer();
    ft.upload(fileURL, encodeURI("http://some.server.com/upload.php"), win, fail, options);

}
```

Comment: I'm new in PhoneGap, so can you provide some code of using file transfer plugin, please?

Comment: Thank you very much! Where exactly do I need to specify the full path to the file? Is it right to use documents://somefile.wav?

Comment: When you do window.src = "myrecording.wav";
    window.mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError); myrecording.wav should be a full path, not the file name. To get the full path you should use the file plugin to get the documents folder and then add the name, it's easier if you just use the media capture plugin that will return the file url